# WooCommerce URL ending in "/?h"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have WooCommerce running in WordPress and all URLs end with "/?h", I can't seem to see where this is set or what it does.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Go to main WordPress settings > Permalinks and change it to something that feet your needs, then save.

Comment: Thanks for this LoicTheAztec, but there are no such settings in the Permalinks section!  I will keep digging.

Comment: I mean also without saying it explicitly, that sometimes you need to go in this permalinks settings and just re-save them, to regenerate some caches (transients), htaccess file wordpress rules… This could solve your issue, without any guaranty.